# Image to Text scanning in Python-Django

Tags: python, django, ocr

I am currently working in a project in *python-django*. The user needs to input some data, currently it is done by typing. I want an alternative method to input data, I prefer Image To Text converter. Anyone please help me to implement a method in *django-python* for the same ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you are looking for the pytesser-it is an OCR in python using tesseract. It is used to convert the text in the image in to string.

pytesser can be downloaded from: https://code.google.com/p/pytesser/downloads/list

You will also need **PIL** to work with images in memory. This can be downloaded from:http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

You can select the appropriate version of PIL according to the python version.

Hope this helps.